# Nativescript - data not binding onTap

Tags: nativescript

At certain point on my xml file i have this:

```
<GridLayout row="2" rowSpan="2" col="2" rows="*" columns="40,*,40" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="right" marginRight="10">
 <Label row="0" col="0" text="+" tap="onTapPlus" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" style="color:black;font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></Label>
 <Label id="" row="0" col="1" text="{{nrItemsTakeAway}}" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" style="color:black;font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif;font-size:20px;text-align:center; width:50px;"></Label>
 <Label row="0" col="2" text="-" tap="onTapMinus" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" style="color:black;font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

So when the user taps on the + button, the onTapPlus function is called and the nrItemsTakeAway is suppose to increment...so just for testing, i did this on my onTapPlus function:

```
function onTapPlus(args) {

const button = args.object;
const page = button.page;
vm.set("nrItemsTakeAway", "4");
page.bindingContext = vm;
```

but it doesn´t work...it is not binding, what am i missing here?

Comment: try binding i.e "page.bindingContext = vm;" on loaded or on navigating to function. then also if its not working create a playground sample.

Comment: Where `vm` comes from in your code? Also the Page's binding context should have been set already upon load, nothing wrong if you update it again but it's simply not required I believe.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering, i forgot the i have this on the page const vm = new Observable(); so i can access it everywhere